# Embedded Postgres и русский язык

Tags: java, intellij-idea, кодировка, консоль

В проекте используется Zonky Embedded Postgres, но вывод сообщений, связанных с этой БД, в консоли IntelliJ Idea сообщений выглядит так

> пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ

и так

> Р’РђР–РќРћ

В чем может быть дело и как исправить отображение текста?

Уже пробовал, не помогло:

1. File - Settings - Editor - Console - Default Encoding - UTF-8
2. Добавить `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` в Custom VM options
3. Добавлять в application.properties строку `zonky.test.database.postgres.client.properties.locale=UTF-8`